# Can i use mvc controllers in an asp net razor project type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I just getting started using Razor pages instead of the MVC approach.

Within my razor page i have a combobox where the user can switch language

```
  <form asp-action="ChangeLanguage" asp-controller="Home" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="returnUrl" name="returnUrl" value="@Model.returnUrl" />
         <select id="culture"
             name="culture"
             class="form-control"
             onchange="this.form.submit();"
             asp-items="@Model.cultureItems"
             asp-for="@Model.requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name">
        </select>
  </form>
```

The combobox is populated with available languages without issues.

When i select the dropdown a post is performed but the method within my controller, never gets the request

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult ChangeLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                new CookieOptions
                {
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
                }
        );

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

After inspecting the request, <strike>the post url seems invalid</strike>

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44350/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:44350
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Am i missing something here?
Generally speaking can i use MVC controllers in Razor pages project types?

The rendered html is

```
<form method="post" action="">

    <input type="hidden" id="returnUrl" name="returnUrl" value="/">

       <select id="culture" name="culture" class="" onchange="this.form.submit();" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required.">
           <option value="el-GR">Ελληνικά (Ελλάδα)</option>
           <option selected="selected" value="en-US">Αγγλικά (Ηνωμένες Πολιτείες)</option>
       </select>

      <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="removed_for_simplicity">
</form>
```

Another update is changing the form as

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/ChangeLanguage">
```

and using

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("Home/ChangeLanguage")]
public IActionResult ChangeLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
```

but now i have an 404 error

Comment: What are you expecting the url to be?  You haven't specified a [Route] attribute or the route in the [HttpPost].

Comment: @Neil you are right. Can you please check the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can finally use MVC controllers in razor pages.
The `MapControllers()` extension method in the `Startup` file does the magic.

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```